# Kinetics of thermal fluctuations in liquid

Tags: statistical-mechanics, biophysics, kinetic-theory

I have an instinct that tells me that particles in water at temperature $T$ should be receiving and emitting "quanta" of energy of size $kT$ at a certain rate $r$. My question is: what is $r$? This would give you kinetics, a timescale to jump out of a potential energy well of depth $U$.

An initial exploration: the kinetic energy of a water particle is $3kT$, right? Or does that only apply to an ideal gas? This would translate to an average speed of 655 m/s. The density of water translates to $ 2.991\times 10^{-29} m^3$ of free volume per molecule, which gives a mean free path of .2 nm. The water molecule should therefore collide every 305 femtoseconds. So $r= 1/(305)\text{fs}^{-1} $.

Does this logic hold?

Comment: this [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1953) "Direct observation of the full transition from ballistic to diffusive Brownian motion in a liquid" can be interesting. they resolve the ballistic displacement of a microscopic particle in liquid, and discuss the relevant time scales (they detect with resolution of ~10 ns).

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a lot of time right now to give a complete answer, but I think can give you some things to think about and get you on track.

First of all the kinetic energy *on average per molecule* of an ideal gas is (3/2)kT  (not sure where you got 3kT).  That said, most gasses do not match the behavior of an ideal gas, although under the right conditions many come close.  Liquids on the other hand, although they are fluids, behave very differently than ideal gases.

This is partly due to the much shorter mean free path as you mention.  However a much larger factor are the intermolecular forces, which become much more pronounced with a shorted mean free path.  *In other words, the molecules of a liquid are not just billiard balls colliding with each other, but have attractive and repulsive forces between them, depending on specifically which molecule we are talking about.*

Water molecules have very a strong tendancy to form hydrogen bonds between multiple water molecules at a time.  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond ).

This means that water is not just a bunch of randomly colliding molecules but actually has structure. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water#Structure )

This can have a very significant effect on the kinetic energy of the water molecules (as compared with molecules that have weaker interactions among themselves, or as compared with an ideal gas in which, by definition, there are *no* interactions between the molecules other than perfectly elastic collisions).

In short, your logic does not hold, for the reasons sited above, both in terms of energy, and in terms of kinetics (time scales).  For kinetics, you would have to also take into account the kinetics of forming and breaking hydrogen bonds during thermal fluctualtions.

I realize this is not a complete answer, but will hopefully get you on track to investigate further.